# Combine values when values meet in loop

Tags: javascript

consider the array:

```
var arr = [
{ val: 12, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 12 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'},
{ val: 54, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 12 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'},
{ val: 34, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 13 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'},
{ val: 21, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 13 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'}];
```

What should i use to find where the timestamp meet, and sum the val ?
so I would get

```
result: [
 { val: 66, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 12 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)' }
 ....
]
```

I tried to loop, but I cannot know to how group and merge?

Comment: Show us your loop

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet below, you should get the idea.

```js
var arr = [
{ val: 12, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 12 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'},
{ val: 54, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 12 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'},
{ val: 34, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 13 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'},
{ val: 21, timestamp: 'Thu Jan 13 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)'}];

var sumArr = [];

arr.forEach(function(element) {
  var sumElement = sumArr.find(function(sumElement) {
     return sumElement.timestamp == element.timestamp;
  });
  if(sumElement) {
     sumElement.val += element.val; 
  } else {
     sumArr.push(element);
  }  
});

console.log(sumArr);
```